# Datagrid refresh not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datagrid to display some information from a SQL table, and then a simple textbox and button to allow users to add records to the database. Problem is, when the user clicks Add, the datagrid SHOULD update, but it doesn't, any ideas? The code in question is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        username.Text = Session["username"].ToString();
        datetime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        BindData();
    }

protected void BindData()
    {
        string SQLQuery = "SELECT * From Filters";

        OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString);

        DataSet resultsDataSet = new DataSet();
        MyConn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter DataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQLQuery, MyConn);
        DataAdapter.Fill(resultsDataSet);
        DGFilters.DataSource = resultsDataSet;
        DGFilters.DataBind();

        if (resultsDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            no_records.Visible = true;
            DGFilters.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            DGFilters.Visible = true;
            no_records.Visible = false;
        }

        MyConn.Close();
    }

    protected void AddFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection MyConn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString);

        MyConn.Open();

        string SQLInsert = "INSERT INTO Filters (FilterString) VALUES ( '" + FilterToAdd.Text + "')";

        OleDbCommand MyCmd = new OleDbCommand(SQLInsert, MyConn);

        MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MyConn.Close();

        DataBind();

    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of your `AddFilter_Click` method you need to call your own `BindData()` so the grid can be refreshed with the new record.  Right now you're calling `DataBind()`, which is a method on the base class Control, which is being applied to your entire web form.  I'm guessing this isn't doing much of anything.

Also, in your Page_Load method, you can probably change this:

```
BindData();
```

to

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     BindData();
```

so that you don't bind your grid twice when the user clicks on the 'add' button.

Comment: cor blimey guvnor. thats what happens when you're trying to code when tired. BindData != DataBind. D'oh!!!!

Comment: @Jonathan -  Uh spotta red bull oughtta fix that :)

Comment: Also - looks like this answer puts me over 100 upvotes for the asp.net badge - so thanks :-P